# NSScrollView responds abnormally to space key

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsscrollview

I am using NSScrollView to display a very long NSView, which width is more than 72000 pixels.  It scrolls well when I drag the knob, and it also responds well to scrollRectToVisible method.

And then, I am using a timer to update the NSScrollView from left to right. All things run well except when I press the space key. When the space key is pressed, the scroll view will stopped for a little while. When I hold the space key down, the scroll view will flash right and left.

I wonder how I can disable the space key for the nsscroll view, because I don't want any space key interactions

I turned on the NSTraceEvent, and found out the following logs:

> 2011-12-22 12:36:51.563 CIVideoDemoGL[255:a0f] Received event: KeyDown at: 131.0,880.0 time: 262523518000 flags: 0x100 win: 0 ctxt: af37 data: 1,252,32,49,32
>
> 2011-12-22 12:36:51.563 CIVideoDemoGL[255:a0f]     In Application: NSEvent: type=KeyDown loc=(0,944) time=262.5 flags=0x100 win=0x0 winNum=47 ctxt=0xaf37 chars=" " unmodchars=" " repeat=1 keyCode=49
>
> 2011-12-22 12:36:51.563 CIVideoDemoGL[255:a0f]     In Window: NSEvent: type=KeyDown loc=(0,944) time=262.5 flags=0x100 win=0x0 winNum=47 ctxt=0xaf37 chars=" " unmodchars=" " repeat=1 keyCode=49
>
> 2011-12-22 12:36:51.564 CIVideoDemoGL[255:a0f] timeout = 62767682588.435905 seconds, mask = ffffffff, dequeue = 1, mode = kCFRunLoopDefaultMode

What should I do to ignore the space key down event for nsscrollview?

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass `NSScrollView`, override `-keyDown:` and in your implementation ignore spaces.

However, I think it's generally unwise to use such a large `NSView`. Instead, you should use a smaller `NSView` and only draw the visible part of the content you're displaying. You will need to implement your own scrolling using `NSScroller` objects but this will give you much better performance than a huge `NSView`.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I have already subclassed NSScrollView, and found out it will never get called for -keDown: method.